# How to display inner shadow in <TextInput> tag?

Tags: css, react-native

How to get inner shadow as below image. I am using below code to get the outer shadow. But how can I get Inner shadow ? Thanks in Advance.

```
<View style={styles.searchBar}>
<TextInput
placeholder={'Suchen...'}
style={styles.inputSearch}
onChangeText={t => this.setState({ text: t })}
value={text}
onSubmitEditing={this.onSearch}
/>
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.clearButton} onPress={this.onClear}>
<Image source={Images.cancelSmall} />
</TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

styles :

```
searchBar: {
flexDirection: 'row',
borderWidth: 0.1,
borderColor: 'grey',
flex: 1,
height: 40,
borderRadius: 40,
backgroundColor: '#fafafa',
shadowColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05)',
shadowOffset: {
width: 2,
height: 3
},
shadowRadius: 6,
shadowOpacity: 1
},
inputSearch: {
paddingLeft: 10,
height: 44,
flex: 1
}
```

[image: Search Bar Image]

Answer (score 2):

you can use [react-native-shadow](https://github.com/879479119/react-native-shadow) it is has inset option

```
import { BorderShadow } from 'react-native-shadow'
render = () => {
    const shadowOpt = {
        width:160,
        height:170,
        color:"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05)",
        border:2,
        inset: true,
        style:{marginVertical:5}
    }

    return (
        <BorderShadow setting={shadowOpt}>
            <TextInput
              placeholder={'Suchen...'}
              style={styles.inputSearch}
              onChangeText={t => this.setState({ text: t })}
              value={text}
              onSubmitEditing={this.onSearch}
              />
             <TouchableOpacity style={styles.clearButton} onPress={this.onClear}>
               <Image source={Images.cancelSmall} />
             </TouchableOpacity>
        </BorderShadow >
    )
}
```

Comment: I just cross checked that library. But nothing seems to be useful to me. Can you please send some code, how to display inner shadow using inset option?

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I will try it now :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearGradient
  style={styles.gradientButton}
  colors={['#040406', '#040406', '#040406', '#444446']}
  start={{ x: 0.48, y: 0.1 }}
  end={{ x: 0.5, y: 0.6 }}
>
```

Use background color dark for a better look

[image: see image]